# Mocking a MySQL server with Java

Tags: java, mysql, sql, eclipse

Since I'm not really proficient with databases, some details may be irrlevant, but I'll include everything:

As part of a project in my University, we're creating a website that uses JSP, servlets and uses a MySQL server as backend.

I'm in charge of setting up the tables on the DB, and creating the Java classes to interact with it. However, we can only connect to the MySQL server from inside the University, while we all (7 people) work mostly at home.

I'm creating an interface `QueryHandler` which has a method that takes a string (representing a query) and returns `ResultSet`. My question is this: How do I create a class that implements this interface which will simulate a database and allow others to use different `DBHandler`s and not know the difference and allow me to test different queries without connecting to the actual MySQL database?

**EDIT**: I'm not so sure on the differences between SQL databases, but obviously all the queries I run on MySQL should run on the mock.

Comment: I think it's more effort to write such a class than to get each of your group members to install MySQL and set up the DB on their computers... +1 for creativity though :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why not just install your own MySQL database for testing?  It runs on Windows, Mac and Linux, and it's not too resource heavy.  I have it installed on my laptop for local testing.

Comment: Won't it be a problem with unit-tests, etc.? As the mock server itself won't be in our trunk (we use SVN) - i.e., other people won't be able to use it.

Comment: @amir, every developer computer should have mysql on it.  It is standard practice in the real world to provide  a database for development.  In this case, put the dbs on the computers of the students.

Comment: If MySQL is a standard part of the development environment, and the unit test @BeforeClass makes sure the tables and data are set up correctly, you're golden.

Comment: I've never worked with DBs in a team. Can you clarify the work flow - how do each person uses his version of the DB, how do you unit test if everyone has a different DB (different content) - or alternatively, how do they synchronize.

Comment: There should be a script that creates/updates the database in source control - every developer's database needs to be on the current structure.  Either the update script or the unit test makes sure the required content is there.

Comment: How does it work? Where does it take the data from? Is it saved somewhere in the repository?

Comment: @Amir, what you are running into is a classic database team development problem; if you don't have multiple installations of the production system (and hence multiple versions) having scripts that will incrementally update local installs of mysql will be an overkill. Instead simply make a checkout process dump the database and then restore the database locally (of course unless it is huge). This would allow developers to develop and test on the local version or central version of database even on same LAN (which can be good for certain tests that stress the DB or can corrupt data).

Answer (score 2):

Your API appears to be flawed.  You should not be returning ResultSets to clients.  By doing so, you are forever forcing your clients to rely on a relational database backend.  Your data access layer needs to hide all of the details of how your data is actually structured and stored.

Instead of returning a ResultSet, consider returning a List or allowing the client to supply a Stream that your data access component can write to.

This will make unit tests trivial for the clients of the API and will allow you to swap storage mechanisms at will.

Comment: what is usually returned instead of ResultSet? How would a List serve the same functionality?

Answer (score 1):

Try [derby](http://db.apache.org/derby/). It's a free server you can use to test against, if you don't mind having to change drivers when you go back to SqlServer. You might be limited in the kind of queries you can run though. I'm not sure if SqlServer has any special syntax outside of standard SQL.

Answer (score 1):

How about using a [HSQLDB](http://hsqldb.org/) for offline tests? It wont behave exactly like a MySQL DB but is a fast in memory SQL DB that should satisfy most of your needs.

Answer (score 1):

The best way in my experience is multiple database instances and or schemas. Normally you'd have one for each user to do their development against/sanity checking the running application, one for an automated build for running unit tests and ideally one for each user to run their unit tests against.  And of course instances/schemas for demos, integration testing.  Apart from the practial side, being able to do this ensures deploying/upgrading the app/database will be pretty near faultless too.

Assuming you have a DAO layer, the only code that needs access to a real database at the unit test level is the DAO implementation, the business layer should be using a mock DAO implementation.